# MSSQL array as parameters in procedure

Tags: javascript, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a sql statement like this. And I pass parameters from code to query like (salary, age)

```
DECLARE @salary NVARCHAR(200);
SET @salary = ?;

DECLARE @age NVARCHAR(30);
SET @age = ?;


SELECT * FROM user WHERE age=@age AND salary >=@salary;
```

I want to have age as an array so I can run statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE age IN someAgeArray AND salary >=@salary
```

How I can achieve this? couldn't find any suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function first, see [SQL User Defined Function to Parse a Delimited String](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str). Then you could do things like this:

```
DECLARE @salary NVARCHAR(200);
SET @salary = ?;

DECLARE @ageList NVARCHAR(200);
SET @ageList = ?;

SELECT * FROM user WHERE age In (SELECT Int_Value FROM fnParseString(@ageList, ',') WHERE Isnumeric(Int_Value) = 1)
AND salary >=@salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use split function and then use like this.

Direct array value do not use as "IN" operator. It give syntax error. If array is comma separated then one thing to be use as

please run the query and read the comment. also some place uncomment code to understand logic.

```
BEGIN
tran
--first option which not give answer as direct query
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(50))

insert into @t values(1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'ghi')

declare @arrayValue varchar(50) = '1,2'
--set @arrayValue = '''' + replace(@arrayValue ,',', ''',''') + ''''

--select @arrayValue
select * from @t where name in ( @arrayValue)

--second option which is dynamic query and give result. Only select portion you will add in dynamic query, this is example.
declare @sqlQuery nVarchar(max) 
set @sqlQuery = '
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(50))

insert into @t values(1,''abc''),(2,''def''),(3,''ghi'')

select id as ''2ndid'', name as ''2ndname'' from @t where id in ( ' +@arrayValue + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery         

--third option 
create table t(id int, name varchar(50))

insert into t values(1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'ghi')

--select * from t where id in ( @arrayValue)
set @sqlQuery = 'select id as ''3rdid'', name as ''3rdname'' from t where id in ( ' + cast ( @arrayValue as nvarchar(500))+ ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery    
rollback
```